# How to use child process module on windows from PhantomJS/CasperJS

Tags: javascript, windows, groovy, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm using CasperJS to test my webApp, the thing is that I need to access a DB to automatize some necessary inputs from my tests.

I'm looking for an alternatives on how to retrieve this data from the DB inside a casperJS js script an finally I decide to use [phantomJS child process module](http://phantomjs.org/api/child_process/) to call a groovy script to connect a DB and make a select and print the result to stdout to get it from CasperJS. However from the sample of the phantomJS can not realize how to do it, based on the sample I made some attempts with [`spawn`](http://phantomjs.org/api/child_process/method/spawn.html) and `execFile` with no luck. i.e I try:

```
var process = require("child_process")
var spawn = process.spawn
var execFile = process.execFile

var child = spawn("groovy", ["script.groovy"])

child.stdout.on("data", function (data) {
  console.log("spawnSTDOUT:", JSON.stringify(data))
})

child.stderr.on("data", function (data) {
  console.log("spawnSTDERR:", JSON.stringify(data))
})

child.on("exit", function (code) {
  console.log("spawnEXIT:", code)
})
```

This doesn't work and not produce any output. I also try directly executing `dir` command directly and also nothing happens.

I try also with linux and it doesn't work either, I try also creating a simple echo `.sh` and nothing..., however in linux when I try to run `ls` command this times it works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some tries I found a way to do it.

Seems that in windows the only way to do it is passing `cmd.exe` as command and `groovy script.groovy` as argument.

So I use

```
var child = spawn("cmd.exe", ["/k","groovy script.groovy"])
```

instead of:

```
var child = spawn("groovy", ["script.groovy"])
```

This way works correctly on windows.

I also found the way to run a shell script on linux, which executes the groovy.It's similar to the windows solution, instead of invoke `.sh` I've to use `sh` command:

```
var child = spawn("sh", ["script.sh"])
```

And script.sh executes the groovy script:

```
#!/bin/bash
groovy script.groovy
```

Comment: I can't make this to work on Windows 10 with latest phantomJS; I tried to run `spawn("cmd.exe", ["/k"])` and it throws error, but nothing useful in the error message. any thoughts?

Comment: @Donbox after `/k` you've to pass the command to execute, `/k` alone does nothing. For example you can try with `spawn("cmd.exe", ["/k","dir"])` to list the files on current directory. Furthermore you can try what I'm telling out of phantom, if you run (keys `Win` +`R`) and put `cmd /k` simply a new cmd is opened, instead if you put `cmd /k dir` a new cmd is opened and the `dir` command is executed showing the file list as result. Hope this clarify your question `:)`

Comment: the issue is `spawn("cmd.exe", ["/k"])` throws error in Phantom

Comment: @DonBox  maybe a better way to get help is to post a new question specifying what you're trying and providing more information about the error `:)` (furthermore as I already told, calling cmd passing `/k` without params has not sense at all).  Anyway could be possible that something is wrong with your `cmd.exe`? Try running `cmd` and there execute `cmd.exe` to see what happens (It's redundant and seems that has not sense to open a cmd to execute a cmd... but who knows, could be it give your mode info).

Comment: var child = spawn("powershell", ["ls","."])